# How to pass multiple array values in ajax url

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, post

I have multiple values, I am trying pass all values in url to controller class at one time.

But last value passed in url.

```
function submitFormData(formData) {
var x = []; 
for(var i = 0;i < formData.length ;i++ ){
    alert(i);
    x = [];
    x.push(formData[i].name);
    x.push(formData[i].email);
    x.push(formData[i].message);
}
 var url= '/userrecords?x='+x;
alert(url);
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
            url: url,
            success: function(result){
            if(result.success == true) {
              $('.alert-success').show();
              $('.alert-danger').hide();
              $("#successmsg").html(result.msg);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert-success").alert('close');
              }, 10000);
            } else {
              $('.alert-danger').show();
              $('.alert-success').hide();
              $("#error").html(result.msg);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert-danger").alert('close');
              }, 10000);
            }
            }
    });
}
```

controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userrecords")
public @ResponseBody StatusResponse saveList(@RequestParam(required = false) String x,Model model)
    throws ParseException, SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
    //read all values here
}
```

What is wrong in my code. And how to read all values in controller.

Comment: Why are you sending data in URL, if you are doing a 'POST' ?

Comment: can you please share the sample formDat and the url

Comment: You dont need 'x' variable to post data, formdata is enough to post your data. In controller you can access your post data by name e.g. 'name', 'message' etc.

Comment: @MUT: How can access data. I am getting null values. My class name is 'UserData'

Comment: Trying using binding your data to model like , `public saveList([Bind(Include = "name,email,message")] Model model' )
{ // save to db db.Add(model)}`
It did work in .net mvc.

Comment: Also you can access individually by model.name, model.message etc.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your array output in JSON and send it to using AJAX and also you have to define content type is JSON.

you can also use jquery ajax it is very simple for request response.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
url:"URL here",
success: function(data) // response 
{}
});
```

Comment: please look at my updated question. i have class so how to get all values in controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post your formdata as ajax data as below.

Pass your **x** veriable as a ajax data.

```
function submitFormData(formData) {
var x = []; 
for(var i = 0;i < formData.length ;i++ ){
    alert(i);
    x.push(formData[i].name);
    x.push(formData[i].email);
    x.push(formData[i].message);
}
 var url= '/userrecords';
alert(url);
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: x,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
            url: url,
            success: function(result){
            if(result.success == true) {
              $('.alert-success').show();
              $('.alert-danger').hide();
              $("#successmsg").html(result.msg);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert-success").alert('close');
              }, 10000);
            } else {
              $('.alert-danger').show();
              $('.alert-success').hide();
              $("#error").html(result.msg);
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert-danger").alert('close');
              }, 10000);
            }
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: Okay,but how can access data in controller class?

Comment: follow this link https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/3-ways-to-receive-data-from-postbacks-in-aspnet-mvc-C2

Comment: i am using java

Comment: Than sorry because i am not familiar with java.